# Error : requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

Following is my javascript/ jquery which runs independently when i save it in text file as html but i am not able to make it work in my VF page.
I am getting the following error when i hit F12

Error is

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://zebra--dev2--c.cs15.visual.force.com/apex/ZEB_RMA_AddProduct?caseId=500e0000007zYko&rmaSelId=a2De0000000dEpDEAU&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
ZEB_RMA_AddProduct:149 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

My code is :

```
<div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="Agree"> Agree</input></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</input></label>

    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>

    <style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #00ff00; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
            $(".box").not(".red").hide();
            $(".red").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
            $(".box").not(".green").hide();
            $(".green").show();
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advane for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following URL in script tag.
https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js
instead
http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js